# Construct of a quantum circuit for the projection $|0\rangle\langle0| + |1\rangle\langle1| $ and its generalizations

Tags: circuit-construction, projection-operator

We can construct a projection over $|0\rangle \langle 0|$ using a quantum circuit with two qubits via the Hadamard test circuit
$$U = H_1 X_2 CZ_{1,2} X_2 H_1 X_1\,, \tag{1}$$
and by performing postselection on the first qubit, imposing the value $|0\rangle$. The corresponding matrix is
$$\Pi_0 = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right]\,.\tag{2}$$

Can we find a general scheme for the projector over $n$ qubits, $\Pi_S = \sum_{j \in S} |j\rangle\langle j|$, given we can construct $U_S$ such that $U_S|0\rangle = \sum_{j \in S} |j\rangle$?

Comment: You defined $\Pi_{01}=I$, which is a trivial projector as you don't need to do anything with your input state.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid the question made no sense. I've fixed that.

Comment: The natural generalisation of the Hadamard test is to assume you have a unitary $\tilde U_S=2\Pi_S-I$ and do controlled-$\tilde U_S$in place of the cZ.